# Neo4j UniqueNodeFactory.getOrCreate(key, value) never returns

Tags: java, neo4j

In a java application using embedded Neo4j (1.8.3) I have subclassed `org.neo4j.graphdb.index.UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory` and have this method in it:

```
    @Override
    public Node getOrCreateIndexedNode(final String key, final Object value) {
            LOG.debug("Get or creating {} Node using [{}={}]", new Object[] { this.type, key, value });
            final Node node = super.getOrCreate(key, value);
            LOG.debug("Got or created {} {} using [{}={}]", new Object[] { this.type, node, key, value });
            return node;
    }
```

Sometimes this call to `getOrCreate(key, value)` never returns. It has been known to be lost for 5 hours before the application was bounced.

What could the possible causes be?
What are the possible solutions?

(The Neo4j instance has approx 25 million nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading from `1.8.x` to `1.9.x` version of `neo4j` fixed this, without any other changes.

Answer (score 1):

You probably run into a lock where you have not released the resources of a previous run. I.e. a transaction still holding an index lock on : prevents your thread from continuing.

Make sure that all your other transactions are progressing and correctly finished.

A thread-dump might help to see which other thread keeps the same lock.

If you're running Neo4j Enterprise you can check the currently open transactions via JMX.

More information about locks in Neo4j:

- read locks are acquired for read operations
- write locks are for updates, like setting, removing properties or labels or adding or removing relationships
- for properties the lock is on the node or relationship
- for adding/removing relationships a write lock is also placed on both nodes
- http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/transactions.html
- http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-unique-nodes.html#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-pessimistic

Comment: You mean like perhaps a long-running query? Where can I learn more detail about locks?

Comment: Updated the answer with some links.

Comment: If I'm, using 1.8.3. can this have something to do with it?
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/405 - would simply upgrading to 1.9.x fix it?

Comment: Reading those last docs you mentioned, is `UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory` deprecated?